# Under what conditions are "Winter Bash Hats" taken away?

Tags: bug, hats

Not that I care much, but it seems odd.

Earlier today I had 8 hats. Now I have 6.

Under what conditions are hats removed? I don't believe I've ever seen that happen before, although perhaps I just never noticed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are/were several bugs with the hat triggers, and unintended hats have been taken away.

[Exhibit 1](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56450361):

> **Hat Maintenance Note:** I fixed a bug in the secret definition of Vexillologist, removed the hat from all users (since a good number who earned it should not have, based on a bug in the sql) and reawarded to all users who should earn it. Anyone who is earning it now will get a new WB inbox notification. So if you are trying to figure out the hat, just look at hats awarded from [now - 5 minutes] and on.

[Exhibit 2](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56467555):

> **mea culpa #3** - really hope this is the last time, but I just cleared all hat owners for balalaika and disciple. Both are secret, and both had something messed up with their triggers (and if I didn't clear them, then would be very hard to figure out what they are for). If you earned themm, they will be awarded to you again shortly.

Comment: I still have the balalaika one, didn't notice it going missing and reappearing, I was wearing it until just recently